# Bootstrap - Button next to search box

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have my search box as follows:

```
<div class="input-group-"> 
                        <form id="form_search" name="form_search" method="get" action="<?php echo site_url();?>"> 
                            <input type="text" name="s" id="search_top" class="form-control" placeholder="Search For Patches"/>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>                         
                        </form> 
                    </div>
```

However, is displays like this: http://gyazo.com/7c6d81ea6341d2d4461c74eb4afb76e2

Any help? Thanks.

EDIT:
Using the bootstrap min css.
https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css

Comment: please post your css also

Answer (score 5):

To make Inline form keep your code like this

```
<form id="form_search" name="form_search" method="get" action="" class="form-inline">
   <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." type="text">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
         <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

http://www.bootply.com/p1BgBMMjN9

**Updated URL:**

http://www.bootply.com/6wVwlnjp0a

**For the Attached Search btn**

http://www.bootply.com/1jX4AhOZ3o

Comment: This works. Can the button actually be attached to the search box?

Comment: Please find the Update Answer

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div><!-- /input-group -->
  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
  </div>
```

This will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

put in inside a div like this.

```
    <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" name="s" id="search_top" class="form-control" placeholder="Search For Patches"/>
<span class="input-group-btn">    
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
    </span>
    </div>
```

That should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" name="s" id="search_top" class="form-control" placeholder="Search For Patches"/>
  <div class="input-group-btn">
     <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because 'search' properties are:

```
display:block; 
width:100%;
```

so change that in css of the class 'form-control' like:

```
.form-control{
display:inline;
width:50px;
}
```

Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do. You want the `Input` and the `Search` on one Line.

Code for this is

```
 <form class="form-inline" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
     <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="font-size:24px"></span></button>
  </div>
</form>
```